# How to simulate a tap with code in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open a windows on my app, but actually this windows open only when I tap on an element. I want to simulate the tap to open this windows by default or simply to open the window automatically.

I've try:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))

view.addGestureRecognizer(payOptionTapGue)

view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.paymentOptionTapped(sender:))))

self.paymentOptionTapped()

payOptionTapGue.addGestureRecognizer(payOptionTapGue)
```

Here is my function that open the windows when I tap:

```
func getPayTapGue() -> UITapGestureRecognizer{
        let payOptionTapGue = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        payOptionTapGue.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.paymentOptionTapped(sender:)))
        return payOptionTapGue
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "by default" ?

Comment: I mean simulate the tap, before to really tap.

Comment: I want to simulate the tap of the function or open the window automatically

Comment: clarify what do you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to lunch this function without trigger the tap gesture, so that's why I'll create new question for this.